# How to use Tailwind background-image in SvelteKit

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#arbitrary-values

this is how I want to use Tailwind bg-image feature. This does not work using SvelteKit next 160 and Tailwind 3.0.9.

Code:

```
<script>
  import globe from '$assets/bg/bg_globe2.png'
</script>

<div
    class={`flex flex-col bg-primary-dark h-64 overflow-hidden bg-no-repeat bg-[right_-14rem_bottom_-10rem] bg-[url('${globe}')]`}
>
  //children
</div>
```

the `bg-[right_-14rem_bottom_-10rem]` class works without problems, so I assume Tailwind has problem with Svelte file paths?

EDIT:
output from console.log(globe) is `src/assets/bg/bg_globe2.png`.

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(globe)`? Can you please add that to your question?

Comment: Tested it on my end with the same result as yours. Arbitrary values work for positioning and show up in the style inspector, but the arbitrary value for the background image is not taken into account even though the path is correct (and tested), so I'm not sure it's a path issue?

Comment: Have you tried [resolving the abiguity](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#resolving-ambiguities)? `bg-[image:url('${globe}')]`

Comment: @JHeth I checked, doesn't change anything. Tested both dev and build+preview, same thing. The path to the image is valid, the tailwind syntax looks correct, but no `background-image` style is generated for the div.

Comment: @ThomasHennes does it at least work with a valid external URL? Like shown here https://play.tailwindcss.com/JHnGi2O6TQ if the answer is yes then I'd say using import for images is the problem.

Comment: @ThomasHennes output from console.log(globe) is `src/assets/bg/bg_globe2.png`. I updated the question.

Comment: @JHeth Just tested with a hardcoded, absolute URL (the same as in your tailwind playground) and the background image doesn't show. So it's clearly not a URL/path issue.

Comment: Apologies, I was wrong. The hardcoded URL gets correctly translated into a `background-image` style for the div (though the image still doesn't show up). So it looks like it **is** indeed a path issue. Sorry for misreporting that. I need some sleep -_-

Comment: I just tested a fresh SvelteKit install and the following worked fine `bg-[image:url('/src/assets/svelte.png')]` but no form of that path as a variable works including the import. The external image URL works both inline and as a variable for me. Tailwind seems to be purging any attempts at using the local file as a variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ❌  Arbitrary values cannot be computed from dynamic values
> `<div class="bg-{ userThemeColor }"></div>`
>
> ✅ Use inline styles for truly dynamic or user-defined values
> `<div style="background-color: { userThemeColor }"></div>`

https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support

Tailwind needs to find the full text value in your code to be able to generate the utility classes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the oneliner util function I came up with based on the response comments I've got, and also handling some path shenanigans on windows.

```
export const toImageUrl = processedImagePath => `url('${processedImagePath.slice(1).replaceAll('\\', '/')}')`
```

and the usage:

```
    import background from '$assets/bg/bg_setup.png?format=webp&quality=90'
    import { toImageUrl } from '$utils/index.js'

    <div style="background-image: {toImageUrl(background)}"/>
```

The query params in image import are due to the usage of `vite-imagetools`